# Modify remote desktop rdp file to sent alt-tab to local machine and not add domain in from of username

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

The title says it all.  I currently start remote desktop from a personal RDP file set up with configuration to get my monitors right.

I have two annoyances.  First I want alt tab to toggle between my local windows tabs (I use alt-q for my remote machines so I can toggle anything as I want it).  I see that option in the UI, but not sure how to set it in my rdp file.

Second every time I open RDP it adds CORP, my domain, in front of my username.  I have to delete that to actually log in.  How do I get it to just add my username without my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two annoyances. First I want alt tab to toggle between my local windows tabs (I use alt-q for my remote machines so I can toggle anything as I want it). I see that option in the UI, but not sure how to set it in my rdp file.

Set it in the UI, save as an .rdp file, then compare their contents. I did this to find out that the .rdp file parameter for "Apply Windows key combinations" is `keyboardhook`, although it is also mentioned in the [format documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files):

| Choice | .rdp file parameter |
| --- | --- |
| "On this computer" | `keyboardhook:i:0` |
| "On the remote computer" | `keyboardhook:i:1` |
| "Only when using full screen" | `keyboardhook:i:2` |

> Second every time I open RDP it adds CORP, my domain, in front of my username. I have to delete that to actually log in. How do I get it to just add my username without my domain?

You can prevent this by adding another domain instead. The computer's own hostname is used as the SAM domain name for all local accounts on that computer – e.g. if your PC is named `MYPC`, then a local account on that PC would be `MYPC\dsollen`.

The username can be saved in .rdp files as `username:s:DOMAIN\user`.